# JSON Decode does not work as expected swift 4

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

if I want to decode my JSON there is something weird happening.

Here's the structs

```
struct chatMessages : Codable {
    var message: [chatMessage]
}

struct chatMessage : Codable {
    var user: String
    var message: String
    var status: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .user)
        message = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        status = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)
        latitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .latitude) ?? 0.0
        longitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .longitude) ?? 0.0
    }
}
```

And here the function

```
   func loadChats() {
        print("Try to load chats...")
        do {
        let jsonData = W.getDataAsData(chatURL)
            print(jsonData)
            print(String.init(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
            print("-----------")
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let chatMessage1 = try jsonDecoder.decode(chatMessage.self, from: jsonData)
            print(chatMessage1)
        }
        catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
```

if the returned JSON is
`{"user":"test","message":"Hello welcome","status":"admin","latitude":0,"longitude":0}`.

its returning `chatMessage(user: "test", message: "Hello welcome", status: "admin", latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)`

but if there are more messages e.g. `[{"user":"user1","message":"Hello welcome","status":"admin","latitude":0,"longitude":0},{"user":"user2","message":"Hello welcome","status":"admin","latitude":0,"longitude":0}]` I cannot get it to work.
Its returning `typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

I've tried with `chatMessages.self` but that didn't go as expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect this inside `init(decoder)` and handle it , but the simple solution is to do this

```
 do {
       let chatMessage1 = try jsonDecoder.decode(chatMessage.self, from: jsonData)
   }
 catch {

    do {
        let chatMessage1 = try jsonDecoder.decode([chatMessage].self, from: jsonData)
     }
     catch {
        print(error)
      }
}
```

also i think it's best to change your backend to return array anway if even there is only one message

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple ,
you must use this :

```
let chatMessage1 = try jsonDecoder.decode([chatMessage].self, from: jsonData)
```

instead of this :

```
let chatMessage1 = try jsonDecoder.decode(chatMessage.self, from: jsonData)
```

in loadChats() function.
because you have array of NSDictionary.

Comment: it's not about use this instead of this , the content may be a dictionary or array so both cases still exist

Comment: The response must be fixed structure. so you decode according it.